# Closed graph correspondence which never contains the whole support

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $I=[a,b]$ with $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$ and denote by $\mathcal{M}(I)$ the set of Borel probability measures on $I$ equipped with the topology induced by the weak convergence of measures.

Does there exist a correspondence $\phi:\mathcal{M}(I) \to 2^I\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ which fulfills $\mathrm{supp}(\sigma)\nsubseteq\phi(\sigma)$ (equivalently $\sigma(\phi(\sigma))< 1$) for all $\sigma\in \mathcal{M}(I)$  while simultaneously having a closed graph: $\{(\sigma,t)\in \mathcal{M}(I)\times I \mid t \in \phi(\sigma)\}$ closed (wrt. the product topology) in  $\mathcal{M}(I)\times I$.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited/clarified, my answer no longer is an answer. So I have deleted it.

Comment: (i) In general, $\mathrm{supp}(\sigma)\nsubseteq\phi(\sigma)$ is not equivalent to $\sigma(\phi(\sigma))< 1$. E.g., take $\sigma$ to be uniform on $[0,1]$ and $\phi(\sigma)=(0,1]$. (ii) The values of $\phi$ are, not in $I$, but in $2^I\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. So, you need to specify a topology on $2^I\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis (i) It is immediately verified that it is equivalent for the case of $\phi(\sigma)$ being closed in $I$. The latter is of course implied by the closed graph property I stated in the question. (ii) The closed graph property $\phi$ shall satisfy is completely independent of the topology on $2^I$. So a topology on $2^I$ is not required. However, you could equip $2^I$ with the topology induced by the upper Hausdorff hemimetric . Then the  required closed graph property should be equivalent to $\phi$ being continuous and $\phi(\sigma)$ being closed in $I$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\M{\mathcal M}\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\th{\theta}$I think the answer is no. Here is the idea of how to show this:

Suppose that such a map $\phi$ exists. In view of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347356/36721) or [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347084/36721), there is a continuous mapping $\psi$ from the set $\F$ of all nonempty closed subsets of $I$ endowed with the Hausdorff metric to $\M:=\M(I)$ such that each $F\in\F$ is the support $S_\mu$ of the measure $\mu:=\psi(F)$. Then the map $\psi\circ\phi\colon\M(I)\to\M(I)$ will be (semi-)continuous in some sense. So, by an appropriate version of the fixed-point theorem, $\mu=(\psi\circ\phi)(\mu)$ for some $\mu\in\M$, whence $S_\mu=\phi(\mu)$, a contradiction.

Comment: If this answer works, it will have to use the fact that the underlying space is an interval and not for example a circle. Perhaps that will be used in the "appropriate version of the fixed-point theorem".

Comment: @user7427029 : What would be wrong with a circle?

Comment: \@IosifPinelis You are right, it's not clear why it wouldn't work for the circle.